# Populate Text box on report based on value on another form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2013

Very novice question but I have a report that has a couple of columns including usernames. I also have a form where a user can select a user name in a combo box and the report will open up only showing records that pertain to that user. Is there a way that I can put a text box on the report that is populated based on what was selected in the combox box of the form which is used to open the report? Note I'm closing the form immediately after opening the report.

Comment: I tried to input something like in the text box on the report but I just receive a #Name? 
=[Forms]![Restructuring Report]![Filteruser_cb]

Comment: Is `[Restructuring Report]` the name of a form or a report? If a form, what does Access tell you when you try this in the Immediate window? `Debug.Print [Forms]![Restructuring Report]![Filteruser_cb]` (Ctrl+g will take you to the Immediate window.)

Comment: simply make a query, that filters the data for the selected user name, and then base the report on the query. The report can be made to open directly at the after update event of the combo box, or by placing a control button on the form. If you need more detailed explanation for any of the above mentioned steps, do let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your Access version is 2007 or later, you can use a `TempVar` to pass the combo box value to the Control Source of your report's text box.

For example, with this as the Control Source for *Username_txt*, the following click event procedure will ensure the correct value is displayed in that text box:

```vb
=[TempVars]![user_name]

Private Sub reportbyuser_bt_Click()
    TempVars("user_name") = Me.Filteruser_cb.Value
    DoCmd.OpenReport "Report by user", acViewReport
    DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
End Sub
```

You can adapt that to use your `Filteruser_cb.Column(n)` instead of `Filteruser_cb.Value`

Comment: this is great. As a VBA / Access beginner, it is helpful to see how things can be done in several different ways.

Answer (score 1):

After some playing around, I was able to figure it out by creating a variable called temp that stored the value of the combo box and fills in the text box on the report with the stored value.

```
Private Sub reportbyuser_bt_Click()
Dim temp As String

temp = Filteruser_cb.Value

DoCmd.OpenReport "Report by user", acViewReport
[Report_Report by user].Username_txt.Value = temp
DoCmd.Close acForm, "Restructuring Report"
End Sub
```

In fact, I don't even need to use the temp and can simply do :

```
[Report_Report by user].Username_txt.Value = Filteruser_cb.Value
```

- Also, just realized that my solution is not very good if the combo box has several different columns in it. I used this instead :

  ```
  [Report_Report by user].Username_txt.Value = Filteruser_cb.Column(n)
  ```

  (With n being the number of the column)

Comment: So when you used `=[Forms]![Restructuring Report]![Filteruser_cb]` as the Control Source for the report text box, you got the `#Name?` problem because that form had been closed.  Was that it?  If so, you could leave the form open but hidden.

Comment: Thanks @Hansup for that explanation. Makes sense. I don't necessarily want to keep forms open and hidden but may try that in the future for other situations.